# AuthorizationPolicy vs AuthorizationFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-authorization

There are many examples of creating authorization policies based on if the user is over the age of 18. Suppose I want to authorize pages based on any age I decide--based on the page I'm showing (i.e. a page might only be available to someone 21 (to drink alcohol), or 25 (to rent a car), or 35 (to be a U.S. Senator), or 55 (for AARP), etc.

Does it make sense to hard-code policies for each of these ages?

Does it make sense to build a lot of custom infrastructure to support some new custom policy thing?

What about something as simple as (obviously, I'm leaving some code to the imagination)...

```
public class AgeAuthorizationAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
   public AgeAuthorizationAttribute(int age)
   {
     ...
   }

   public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext ctx)
   {
      if (!IsNotOldEnough())
         ctx.Result = new ForbidResult();
   }
}
```

And then this could be used anywhere, like

```
[AgeAuthorization(25)]
public class MyController
{
}
```

Is using a filter like this frowned upon now? Is there an **easier** way to implement this via policies? And is there **any reason** to prefer implementing this via policies?

Answer (score 0):

> Does it make sense to hard-code policies for each of these ages?

Actually, either in controller or somewhere in more granular level we have to define our condition hard coded. Thus, either you pass your argument in AgeAuthorization filter or you would check that within your AgeAuthorization [authorization policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0#apply-policies-to-mvc-controllers) we have to check somewhere we would rquire to check the actual age to check.

> Does it make sense to build a lot of custom infrastructure to support
> some new custom policy thing?

As authorization policy consists of one or more requirements which results a richer, reusable, testable authorization structure, therefore, you always open to customize your policy. You could [check similar implementation here in official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0#requirements)

> Is using a filter like this frowned upon now?

Although, [authorization policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and [action filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#action-filters) in some context can do similar stuff, we could consider your scenario as using both  authorization policy and action filter we could meet the requirement that's we would restrict the access based on the age.

However, [authorization policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0) has some advantage in regards of its supportability. For example, [in razor page we cannot use action filter.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#action-filters). In this aspects,  authorization policy would have more flexibility.

> Is there an easier way to implement this via policies? And is there
> any reason to prefer implementing this via policies?

In regards of asp.net core MVC and asp.net core web Api, you could use both policy based authorization and action filter and the implementtaion is pretty similar. So I would say, this seems the general way to validate age kind of restriction which I have already shared above.

A part from above concept, you even can consider [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and [ValidationAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-attributes) to meet your implementaion.

**Note:** As at this moment you have no coding challenge, so I am not sharing any implmentaion details. If you would start implementing anything further, please feel free to [check our official document above.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0#apply-policies-to-mvc-controllers) or you could post your concern on new question as well.

Comment: If I want to create a new controller with an age restriction of 32, I can simply apply the attribute AgeAuthorization(32). If I were to do this via policies, I would have to modify my startup, add a new policy (using requirements, etc.) and then add the appropriate attribute to my controller. The second option seems like much more work. Why would I choose the second option over the first? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Right you are, to point your sceond question, its because of your flexibility and supportability but almost they does same. However, the order of execution has first precedence for authorization policy. I think you are correct in concept and not missing anything.